# clear cache interceptor struts2 not working

Tags: struts2

I have written an interceptor to prevent caching but the pages still cache.

Interceptor:

```
public class ClearCacheInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation)throws Exception{
        String result = invocation.invoke();

        ActionContext context = (ActionContext) invocation.getInvocationContext();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.get(StrutsStatics.HTTP_REQUEST);
        HttpServletResponse response=(HttpServletResponse) context.get(StrutsStatics.HTTP_RESPONSE);

        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);

        return result;
    }

    public void destroy() {}
    public void init() {}
}
```

Struts.xml

```
<struts>
  <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true"/>
  <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />

  <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
    <interceptors>  
      <interceptor name="caching" class="com.struts.device.interceptor.ClearCacheInterceptor"/>
      <interceptor-stack name="cachingStack">      
        <interceptor-ref name="caching" />     
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />    
      </interceptor-stack> 
    </interceptors>

    <action name="Login" class="struts.device.example.LogIn">
      <interceptor-ref name="cachingStack"/>
      <result>example/Add.jsp</result>
      <result name="error">example/Login.jsp</result>
    </action>
  </package>
</struts>
```

Application works fine; it executes interceptor but it doesn't prevent caching.

Comment: By "it's not clearing the cache" do you mean "it's still caching"?

Comment: Use Firebug or Chrome's developer tools to view the response to see if your HTTP headers (Cache-Control, Pragma, and Expires) are being set.

Comment: @StevenBenitez : i checked using firefox developer tool to see live HTTp header information, but these headers(Cache_ Control,Pragma and Expires) are not being set.    What mistake I am doing in my code.???

Comment: No idea. Why don't you do some debugging? You at least know now that the headers aren't being set, which is probably why the browser is continuing to cache the page. You have several System.out.println lines in your interceptor. Are those output lines making it to the console? Try setting a break point and stepping through the code.

Comment: @StevenBenitez: thanku so much.....all that i have done...yes the System.out.println lines were making it to console.Now I am able to set the cache parameters. I have found my mistake (refer answer here) ,but still even after caching ,on back button it gets me the previous page's content.Which I dont want in my application. Is there any option in struts2 or need to go with one option left --Disable browser's back button.

Comment: You can't disable a browsers back button reliably in most browsers, nor should you be able to. Clear your cache completely and try again, just to make sure that the browser isn't loading a cached version of the page from before your headers were being set properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem. Thanks to developer tools for helping me to trace out.

A slight sequence change in my code helped me out: as per [the Struts 2 interceptor docs](http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/writing-interceptors.html) the result is rendered *before* `invocation.invoke()` returns. Setting the headers before the result is rendered back to the client sets the headers in the returned result.

i.e.,

```
public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation)throws Exception{
    HttpServletResponse response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();

    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);

    return invocation.invoke();
}
```