# How to Change Struts2 back button behavior?

Tags: struts2

I am new to struts 2 frameword I would like to discuss my problem using an example..

Lets take a login and a dashboard example.

I am doing login and after successful login i moved to dashboard, from dashboard again by submitting a form i move to the Dummy page, but on this page when i press browser back button then it navigate me direct to the login screen and not on dashboard.

same problem for the reloading the page if any validation error comes then i again move reload the current page with the errors, but in this case if i press back button then it shows same page without errors.

Information added after edit ->

When i do login my url on browser is `http://localhost:8080/MyWebApp/jsp/LoginAction`
and now am on dashboard when am submitting a form from here and navigating to Dummy page my browser shows url `http://localhost:8080/MyWebApp/jsp/DummyAction` and am on dummy page

Now the problem is here when am pressing back button i should go to the Dashboard page but it is not happening and it throws me at Login page and my browser url is now `http://localhost:8080/MyWebApp/jsp/LoginAction`

Note : I am using post method to submit the form

any help will be appreciated, sorry for my english.

Comment: How do you want to change it? Post JSP's relevant code.

Comment: @ Roman C, thanks 4 reply I want back button to work as normal which we usually access the web.
edited the que.

Comment: The back button takes you back, S2 has nothing to do with this. Sounds like you're missing the post-redirect-get pattern: if you forward a response you're not changing the browser history.

Comment: Back button is managed by the browser, normally you should not change that behavior as it allows to return to the previous pages and doesn't have gaps between pages.

Comment: @ Dave, thanks 4 reply. you are right my form was submitted twice in this case, but how should i get rid of this problem. i want to stay same page i.e. on dashboard when back is pressed

Answer (score 0):

Struts2 is completely server-side, client-side back button has nothing to do with Struts2.

One solution can be to [disable the browser back button](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=disable+browser+back+button+jquery&oq=disable+browser+ba&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.4078j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Yes, u r right but I don't want to disable it. I want both forward and backward navigation facility.

Answer (score 0):

1. Disable browser caching using [interceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009049/clear-cache-interceptor-struts2-not-working)
2. Enable csrf using [s:token](http://www.journaldev.com/2281/struts2-token-interceptor-to-handle-double-form-submission-problem)